# WebView - any way to edit loaded webpage? Add some scripts or styles?

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-phone, winjs

I'm creating web browser where user can quickly hide some elements that interrupts while reading content.

I think the best way to hide divs selected by user would be editing source (html) of loaded page. Is it possible? I don't see any methods like that in reference.

I use WinJS to create apps for WP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can inject javascript into any page using this syntax:

```
var asyncOp = webView.invokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.write('Hello World!')" });      
asyncOp.oncomplete = completedHandler;
asyncOp.onerror = errorHandler;
asyncOp.start();
```

You can use this to modify any part of the loaded HTML page.

Comment: Can you help me? I'm trying to use it in my app, but it doesn't want to work :/ http://pastebin.com/nujHPcDL Code that I want to execute works properly in web browsers. Interesting thing is that oncomplete() and onerror() functions aren't executed, I've used logs and I've put some breakpoints in Visual Studio there and code inside those functions isn't used by my app. Why is that?

Comment: I've been staring at this for a while and can't figure out why the functions aren't running.  However, if you use a button to explicitly call a function which uses invokeScriptAsync, it works to change the background of the google logo to black.

Comment: ok, when i use button, it works, but only on PC :P When i try to open my app on my lumia appears an error: "Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101."